# Is it common to use “grocery” as a verb?

Tags: verbs, nouns, word-usage

My favorite NY-Times columnist Maureen Dowd who consistently supplies me the material for posting questions in EL&U site begins today’s (December 8) article titled “A Lost Civilization” with the line:

> “My college roommates and **I used to grocery shop** and cook together.
>   The only food we seemed to agree on was corn, so we ate a lot of
>   corn.”

All of Cambridge, Oxford, and Merriam-Webster dictionaries register “grocery” as a noun meaning “grocery store (Cambridge),” “grocer’s shop or business (Oxford)” and “(1) grocer’s store, (2) groceries sold by a grocer.” However, none of them lists “grocery” as a verb.

I know a noun are often used as verbs like 'bicycle a trip,' 'pen a letter,' and 'market a new product,' but is “grocery” widely used as a verb meaning ‘to visit a grocery store,’ or simply ‘shop around’?

Is the use of "X-shop" as a verb 'trendy' and universal?

Can I say “I barber shop once a month," "He golf shopped to buy a new club," "She used  to barger shops for a lunch," "I sport shopped to buy a new ski wear," "I computer shopped a new i-phone model yesterday," "I book shopped for a Jeffery Archer's paperback yesterday," and "I pawn shopped to loan $300," without being frowned?

Comment: The verb is two words, "grocery shop", that's all.

Comment: _Shop_ is the verb; that verb can be modified with a number of qualifiers; e.g., we can [_window shop_](http://lyricsplayground.com/alpha/songs/g/georgiegirl.shtml), [_clothes shop_](http://www.cafemom.com/answers/870993/Favorite_place_to_clothes_shop_for_the_kids), [_shoe shop_](http://www.qvc.com/ShoeShoppingWithJane.content.html), or _grocery shop_. Just like _grocery store_ refers to a store that sells groceries, _grocery shopping_ refers to a trip where you buy (mostly) groceries.

Comment: @Mark Beadles. If so, isnt ‘grocery-shop’ less confusing as a verb than separating two words?

Comment: @YoichiOishi: I suppose, according to the rules of grammar, a hyphen could be used, but, for whatever reason, I've never seen one with the verbs _shop_ or _shopping_.

Comment: Hyphenation is usual with the participle used as an adjective, but it's not so common with the infinitive. My guess is that these are constructions that arise in oral discourse; when they enter the written language it's usually in semi-formal contexts like Dowd's column; so the usual two-words–to–hyphenate–to–single-word progression gets blurred. *Cherry pick/cherry-pick/cherrypick* is another example.

Comment: @Yoichi: In common parlance, we're much happier to use the (gerund?) form *grocery shopping* (or tchrist's *berry picking, kite flying, babysitting*). It's a bit peripheral to focus on whether the two words are fused or hyphenated, but you need to note that some such pairs are more common, and thus more flexibly-used than others. Thus, *"Will you babysit tonight?"*, and *"Let's just window-shop today!"* are "well-received", as you would say. But *"Do you want to kite-fly tomorrow?"* isn't, for the vast majority of speakers.

Comment: ...also, as you know, Dowd likes to push at the boundaries of "acceptable usage" sometimes. Most people would speak of *shopping for groceries* - but that doesn't suit her purposes, since she wants a short verb that she can link using *and* to another verb *cook*, before modifying both verbs with *together*. That extra word *together* doesn't want to be too far away from the start of its "scope" (or, *she* doesn't want it to be, depending on how you look at these things! :)

Comment: Pawn-shop shop is pushing it a bit. _Cooks leaves and grocery shops_ might make a good title for a book.

Comment: The construct is *to go **something** shopping*, or just *to **something** shop.*  Both mean shopping for that something.  It’s like going stargazing.  Verbal nouns like this, coupled with their complements, are easily made in English.  It’s just that *to **anything** shop* has itself gained currency as a verb. Others end up that way, too, like babysitting.  I could see someone saying they stargazed yesterday, but it probably isn’t normal as an inflected verb is formal writing. It’s fine in conversation.

Comment: Agree with Mark Beadles. While it is possible to say "I used to quickly grocery shop," "I used to grocery quickly shop" is wrong. To grocery shop is a compound verb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends what you mean by ‘common’. The Corpus of Contemporary American English has 10 records for *to grocery shop*, and the Oxford English Dictionary has this citation 1979 citation from the Arizona Daily Star:

> Volunteers are needed to grocery shop for elderly shut-ins.

There are no records for the string in the British National Corpus.

If you say any of the sentences in your final paragraph, it is by no means certain that you will be understood. *Barber shop*, as a verb, sounds as if you’re shopping for barbers, an unlikely activity. The verb *grocery shop* is established, to the limited extent that it is, because shopping for groceries is fairly common. Language exists to meet a need, and there would seem to be even less of a need for a special verb for shopping for golf clubs than there is for shopping for groceries.

Comment: But at least those people who want to go *golf club shopping* would expect their activity to be understood. I don't believe enough people go shopping for barbers that we need be concerned about them, but we should spare a thought for those who go shopping for windows!

Answer (score 6):

*Grocery shop* is a common collocation in which *shop* is used in the verb sense and *grocery* is a colloquially back-formed singular of the object of shopping: groceries (groceries being what one purchases at a grocery). The long form would be *We used to shop for groceries together*.

Comment: People who go berry picking and kite flying when they really should be babysitting would agree with that analysis.

Comment: The OED gives the etymology of _grocery_ not as a back-formation from _groceries_, but as a combination of _grocer_ + the suffix _-y_.

Comment: @BarrieEngland  That is true; but that refers to *grocery* in the sense of the grocer's trade or establishment. What the grocer *sells* is (as the *OED* also says) *groceries* : one does not *\*shop for a grocery*. In the collocation *grocery shop*, the singular is a back-formation.

Comment: @StoneyB. Understood.

Answer (score 1):

'Grocery' is a noun; 'shop' is the verb, with 'grocery' modifying it, shopping for groceries.

> I used to grocery shop and cook.

is used to say that the speaker shopped *for food* in order to cook it.

If they said:

> I used to shop and cook.

it sounds a bit incongruous because the default meaning of 'to shop' is to shop for *clothes* (and so to shop for clothes and then cook sounds like a lot to do in one sentence.

> I went grocery shopping

is the more likely way you'd see the restriction of shopping for food. 'To grocery shop' sounds a little strange by itself (not so common). This is borne out by a [gooogle ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=grocery+shop%2Cgrocery+shopping%2Cfood+shop%2Cfood+shopping&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3) only partially, showing that after 1970 'grocery shopping is much more common, but before 'to grocery shop was more common.

Comment: The conclusions you draw from your Google Ngram are incorrect. Before 1970, "grocery shop" was a noun, meaning a shop you buy groceries at. It is only recently that "grocery shop" is being used as a verb. See [this google ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+grocery+shop%2Cgrocery+shopped%2Cgrocery+shop&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) for corroboration..

Comment: @PeterShor: excellent point...it's hard to make reliable inferences from such searches.

Answer (score -1):

NO, "grocery" is a noun and can't be used as a verb. You could use other words such as shop, purchase, buy, procure among others.

Comment: "Grocery" in the OP's example sentence functions as an adverb because it modifies the verb "shop" in _grocery shop_. Were "shop" a noun in this phrase, the noun _grocery_ would be functioning as an adjective because it'd be modifying the noun "shop". I'd never say that '"grocery" is a noun and can't be used as a verb'. We native speakers of English love to verb nouns, so I can imagine some dude saying something like "Hey, let's grocery again, like we did last Sunday, let's grocery again, like we did last week!" Chubby Checkout anyone?

Comment: @BillFranke No, you should not think of *grocery* as an adverb that modfies *shop*.  As StoneyB wrote, you should think of it as an **object complement placed in front of the verb** — and therefore a noun. It here works a bit like it does when making verbal nouns like house-sitting and dogcatching and birdwatching, or rum-running or cattle rustlin’ or sheep sheering or wool-gathering. See how those are all noun+verb cast into an *-ing* form, and meaning something that’s verbing that noun? It is the same thing when going anything shopping: you’re shopping for anything.

Comment: @tchrist: I said **it _functions_ as an adverb because it modifies a verb**, not **it _is_ an adverb**. There's a considerable difference. All adjectives (other than galore etc.) are preposed subject/object complements and some adverbs are preposed verb phrase & adjective complements. What does that tell an EFL student? Nothing of value. In addition, this kind of terminological quibble is important only for professional linguists when they analyze the language. It's of no value to civilians. **What's important is what the word does in any particular context**, not what it's called.

Comment: Modifiers change the meanings of words in many ways. One way is to restrict them, as Dowd has done in the phrase _grocery shop_. Had she not said _used to grocery shop and cook together_, the verb "shop" would naturally have been understood to include clothes shopping and other kinds of shopping, but she wanted to restrict the meaning to food-related shopping, probably to make the sentence more cohesive and to focus on her and her roommates' preprandial activities.

Comment: @BillFranke  You and I, I think, come from a very different world than tchrist. We're pre-Chomskyans; our fundamental terms are the Parts of Speech, and we employ those to describe functions. tchrist is post-Chomskyan; for him functions are fundamental and have their own terminology, while the POS are employed primarily to classify word-forms. I am coming to believe that although it is hard for *me* to understand his terminology, it will be easier for the student to understand.

Comment: @Bill (4 above): We really need to have someone enforce new and unarguable terminology from above (not that anyone would accept it). The word _modify_ is variously and confusingly defined: Do italics become adverbial when a verb is italicised? Bolding or highlighting? If we restrict the definition to words and strings: Can _mere_ be said to be modifying _youth_ in any even vaguely central sense in _mere youth_? An _alleged_ criminal may not even be a criminal, and a _former president_ almost certainly isn't a president. I think a term meaning just 'adding/adjusting information' needs coining.

Comment: user31968: I've come across a law which says otherwise: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9217/is-verbing-in-i-medalled-in-volleyball-correct . However, I agree that verbing _grocery_ would be idiosyncratic in the extreme. I do disagree with you, however, when you say "grocery" is a noun. Is _particle_ a noun in _particleboard_? Is _black_ an adjective in _blackboard_? Is _particle_ a noun in _particle-board_? I'd say that the open variant, _particle board_ is as unitary as the other two variants, and should be considered to be **a** (compound) noun. _Grocery-shop_ is a compound verb.

Comment: @E: Yes, the terminology is confusing, partially because it's composed of common terms like "modify" (verb) & technical terms like "complement" (noun). The complement "former" in "former president" both completes & modifies (restricts because it changes the meaning of) "president". But so what? It's not the name we give things that determines how they function: names are frequently arbitrary. I don't grok your remarks about **bold** & _italics_: seems to be snark to me. What's "a central sense" in "mere youth"? An _important_ sense? Yes, it expresses the speaker's attitude about youth.

Comment: I'm not all that fond of this answer, but I really enjoyed the discussion it generated.

Comment: @Bill: (a) We need metalanguage to discuss English meaningfully, so we need agreed-on meanings rather than Humptyisms. (b) I've seen definitions of senses of _modify_ (... a verb say) that would include 'changing font size'.

Comment: ... (c) Can we use the reasonable definition: **adjectives express attributes of the noun’s referent** _former_ in say _former president_ doesn't do this - it has an almost determiner function, not saying what sort of president, but locating the term of office in time. _Fake_ in _fake diamond_ doesn't tell us 'what sort of diamond'. _Mere_ in a _mere youth_ doesn't express something directly about this particular person - as you say, it is a comment on youth in general. The AHDEL defines the grammatical sense of modify thus: to qualify or limit the meaning of. **Not** make _gross_ changes.

Comment: @E: (a)Totally agree. (b) Orthography isn't English usage or grammar, so this definition's outré except when dealing with orthographic representations (eg, **bold font** = primary stress), which indicates tone of voice & may affect the meaning of printed language (painting & photography are art, not language). (c) There are at least 5 types of adjective: 1) Possessive, 2) Descriptive, 3) Numerical, 4) Demonstrative, 5) Interrogative. There are other possibilities (I don't have my Quirk & Greenbaum handy): 6) Predicative, 7) Absolute, 8) Nominal, 9) Common, 10) Resultative, 11) Predicative.

Comment: ...Ergo, the "reasonable definition" you offer is far too limited because it's restricted to attributive ADJs. _Fake diamond_ says _not a diamond_, which tells us "paste, glass, crystal, zircon, etc.,: ie, synthetic, not natural". _Former president_ says _not president now_. "Tall" is attributive for a person; "green" is attributive for a frog but not a box that can be painted (even though MW says "[attribute](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/attribute) : 1. : an inherent characteristic; also : an accidental quality", which is contradictory.

Comment: ... (d) I agree with ADHEL: "to qualify or limit the meaning of", but that's too vague to be useful in nitpicky analyses. (e) Terminology must be better & consensus is required. I'm pessimistic about these two: terminology = ideology & human nature's intrinsically schismatic. (f) If only everyone shared "my reasonable view of things, the world would be a better place, a peaceful place, a place without war, poverty, hunger, crime, & accusations of blasphemy & apostasy". This is over-the-top, I know, but I'm an inveterate cynic. (g) Stipulation without consensus = continued chaos.

Comment: @B: (ab) I've come across 'adverbs modify verbs but adjectives qualify nouns', which distinction obviously isn't agreed upon by all grammarians. (c) Your 11-or-so categories mix semantic and syntactic properties / requirements. I'm afraid I don't hold unswervingly to the dictates of either ACGEL or CGEL (and it's impossible always to accept the pronouncements of both) though their contents are of course priceless. At http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/aboutus/people/heinz/assocadj.pdf  : One such case is that of the ‘associative’ adjectives in English

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6676/discussion-between-edwin-ashworth-and-bill-franke)